# My HTML/ Javascript calculator will not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax, calculator

I am writing a simple UI calculator and it was working perfectly until i optimized some of the functions to make the calculator actually calculate. I've reviewed my code and I can't find what is wrong with the JavaScript. the snippet only includes the numbers 1,2,3 but the actual thing has 1-9.

```js
var resultline_str = " ";
   var multidigit = 0
   var space = 0
   var operating = [];
   
   function type1(){
    resultline_str += " 1";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(1);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '1';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '1';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type2(){
    resultline_str += " 2";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(2);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '2';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '2';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type3(){
    resultline_str += " 3";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(3);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '3';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '3';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
            function type_plus(){
    resultline_str += " +";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('+');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
   
   function type_minus(){
    resultline_str += " -";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('-');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
   
   function equals(){
    if(operating.length() != 3){
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error';
     multidigit = 0;
     place = 0
     return;
    }else{
     if(operating[1] === '+'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] + operating[2];
     }else if(operating[1] === '-'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] - operating[2];
     }else if(operating[1] === '*'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] * operating[2];
     }else if(operating[1] === '/'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] / operating[2];
     };
    };
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating = [];
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 0;
   };
   
   function clear_line(){
    resultline_str = " ";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating = [];
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 0;
   };
   
   function times(){
    resultline_str += " *";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('*');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
   
   function divide(){
    resultline_str += " /";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('-');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
```

```css
#grid{
    height:510px;
    width:260px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:10px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    
   }
#result{
    float:right;
    height:525px;
    width:950px;
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid black;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:strong;
   }
td{
    padding:30px;
    font-size:40px;
    size:400%;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:bold;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='grid'>
  <table>
 <tr>
  <td id="1" onclick='type1()'>1</td>
  <td id="2" onclick='type2()'>2</td>
  <td id="3" onclick='type3()'>3</td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td id="=" onclick='equals()'>=</td>
  <td id="+" onclick='type_plus()'>+</td>
  <td id="-" onclick='type_minus()'>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="times" onclick='times()'>X</td>
  <td id="clear" onclick='clear_line()'>C</td>
  <td id="divide" onclick='divide()'>%</td>
 </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   <div id="result">
 <b></b>
   </div>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does the browser console output any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You had several ; missing and you built a string with variables together with `<br>` not quoted as html.

I fixed your issues added it to a [JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/o0zsbrtf/).
Now you just need to parseInt() the values for the calculator to work.

```
else{
                    if(operating[1] === '+'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + operating[0] + operating[2];
                    }else if(operating[1] === '-'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + operating[0] - operating[2];
                    }else if(operating[1] === '*'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + operating[0] * operating[2];
                    }else if(operating[1] === '/'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + operating[0] / operating[2];
                    };
                };
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Though I'd change that '<br>' to '<br />'

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work for addition. It simply concatenates the two numbers even when i put parseInt on each input

Comment: Never mind, I just had to change the priorities of the addition and it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, sorry for bugging you, but now I've fixed everything but theres a problem. When the second number of the operation is multidigit, the answer isn't right. I don't even know where the answer comes from. Example 8 + 48 = 92.

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you upload your whole solution on JS-fiddle?
Here is an example of a calculator I made once:
http://jsfiddle.net/8oeehm0y/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nzdj7vqo/1/ this is really inefficient compared to yours i'm fairly new. I just copied and pasted from notepad++ .

Comment: When you type 123 + 456 and press equals,
the operating array contains `[12356, "+", 4]`
Maybe that helps. Try writing `debugger;` in your code, and have your console open when u run it, to track what's going on

Comment: This is the problem:
`if (multidigit === 0)`
When pressing multiple digits this variable doesn't add up

Answer (score 0):

You have got a minor syntax error on the code below. Notice the "**br**" tag? It is supposed to be part of a string.

This is how I debug and you might be interested to fix this in future. If you are using Chrome browser, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to bring up the console and you should see something like line 165 syntax error and something along the lines of  unexpected character "<" blah blah. That should pretty much give you a hint on what went wrong.

```
if(operating[1] === '+'){
                    resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] + operating[2];
                }else if(operating[1] === '-'){
                    resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] - operating[2];
                }else if(operating[1] === '*'){
                    resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] * operating[2];
                }else if(operating[1] === '/'){
                    resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] / operating[2];
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the chrome/firefox developer functions, like Tendious mentioned.

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ou6tsqu/)
                        i

```
if(operating[1] === '+'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + (operating[0] + operating[2]);
                    }else if(operating[1] === '-'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + (operating[0] - operating[2]);
                    }else if(operating[1] === '*'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + (operating[0] * operating[2]);
                    }else if(operating[1] === '/'){
                        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br>' + (operating[0] / operating[2]);
```

You don't need parseInt() if you clamp (operating[0]+operating[2]) and so on.

Then its no string concatenation anymore. Instead its an mathematical operation(because both variables are of type number). The concatenation with "
" is done after the mathematical.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a few issues inside the code... I will separate them with lines.

---

```
if(operating.length() != 3){
```

You placed a `()` when you called for the `length` of `operating` on the first line of the `equals` function, when it should have been called like so...

```
if(operating.length != 3){
```

---

In the `else` block of the `if` statement in the `equals` function, you added several strings together like this one...

```
resultline_str = resultline_str + <br> + operating[0] + operating[2];
```

When you added `<br>` inside the strings, you forgot to put quotes around it. This happened several times in this block. It should look like this:

```
resultline_str = resultline_str + "<br>" + operating[0] + operating[2];
```

---

I also noticed when running the modified code that `1 + 2 = 12`.

The issue there is that in the same block mentioned above, you added numbers to a string which, instead of calculating, just put the numbers next to eachother.

```
resultline_str = resultline_str + "<br>" + operating[0] + operating[2];
```

Should instead be

```
resultline_str = resultline_str + "<br>" + (operating[0] + operating[2]);
```

I put parenthesis around the added numbers so that they would calculate before being attached to the string.

Comment: I fixed all those issues in the example above, but thank you for explaining what he missed +1

Answer (score 0):

I re-coded your calculator.  If you define the calculator in json, then you can change how it works and is laid out easily:

```
var calculator = {
        buttons: [
            [
                { value: '1', type: 'num' },
                { value: '2', type: 'num' },
                { value: '3', type: 'num' }
            ],
...
```

and you can keep the html simple like this:

```
<div class="calculator"></div>
```

You then generate the html by stepping through the json like this:

```
var buildCalculator = function( target, buttons){
        $(target)
            .append( 
                $('<div />')
                    .addClass( 'result' )
            )
            .append( 
                $('<div />')
                    .addClass( 'equation' )
            );
        _.each(buttons, function (row, r) {
            $(target)
                .append( 
                     addRow(row, r)
                )
        });
    },
    addRow = function(row, r){
        var div = $('<div />')
            .addClass( 'row row-' + r );
        _.each(row, function (col, c) {
            div.append( 
                    addCol(col,c)
                )
        });
        return div;
    },
    addCol = function addCols(col,c){
        return $('<button />')
            .addClass( 'col col-' + c + ' js-' + col.type + ' ' + col.class )
            .attr( 'data-action', col.action )
            .html( col.value );
    };
buildCalculator('.calculator', calculator.buttons );
```

Calculate with a simpler core function (that 'cases' variable is just a different way of coding a case/switch):

```
    calculate = function() {
        var p = 0,
            result = 0,
            op = 'add',
            eqAdd = function(i) { result = result + equation[i].value; },
            eqSub = function(i) { result = result - equation[i].value; },
            eqTimes = function(i) { result = result * equation[i].value; },
            eqDiv = function(i) { result = result / equation[i].value; },
            cases = {
                'add': eqAdd,
                'sub': eqSub,
                'times': eqTimes,
                'div': eqDiv
            };
        _.each(equation, function (eq, i) {
            if(op){
                if (cases[op]) cases[op](i);
                op = false;
            } else {
                op = eq.action;
            }
        });
        $('.result')
            .html( result );
    };
```

and finally, process the button clicks using jQuery:

```
$('.js-num').click( function(){
    equation[position].value = equation[position].value * 10 + parseInt($(this).text());
    $('.equation .pos-' + position).html( equation[position].value );
    calculate();
});
$('.js-calc').click( function(){
    position++
    addPosition( $(this).text() );
    equation.push( { type: 'calc', action: $(this).attr('data-action') } );
    $('.equation .pos-' + position)
        .addClass('calc')
        .html( equation[position].value );
    position++
    addPosition( '0' );
    equation.push( { type: 'num', value: 0 } );
    calculate();
});
$('.js-clear').click( function(){
    clear();
});
```

<strike>This isn't fully baked - it just calculates each item as it goes through, which means it doesn't calculate multiplication before addition.  To do that, I'd pre-process the equation when calculating it and nest the items between all multiplication and division symbols.  That requires a recursive function to walk the json.</strike> - I fixed this in the fiddle.

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/69487mwx/